# Encryption key: Can I use obfuscation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, encryption, key

I am building an iOS app for someone. The app will be used to take mock exams on for a professional license. The question data is stored in Core Data but the question and answers strings need to be encrypted as the client spent a lot of time writing them and doesn't want someone else stealing his work to use in a competing product.

So what I want to do is set the attributes in core data to transformable, use a custom NSValueTransformer to transform the strings to NSData and while they are being transformed use RNEncrypt to encrypt and decrypt.

So far so good.

Here is my predicament: I need to use a key to encrypt and decrypt the data but how do I get/create it?

My options:

- hardcode it == bad!
- generate key and store in keychain == not the right type of security. i.e.. does not protect against owner of the device.
- generate key from user password == no other reason for the user to have to login.
- the app connects to a server and gets a key with some authentication stuff(I don't know what is involved exactly) == I don't want to rely on a network connection for the app to work.
- obfuscation, I feel like if I create a string from bits of other strings and method sigs and then hash it then that will be enough == It probably won't be.

My questions then are these:
- Obfuscation, can it be enough, has anyone else had success with it?
- From my research I've learnt that a hacker with an ipa can see all the hardcoded strings, class names and method sigs but they can't see the code inside the methods (is that correct?), so how could someone read the key if it was built up/generated inside a method?
- As the title, Can I use Obfuscation?
- Are there any options I have missed?

For the record, if I have to then I'll make people register and login.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot store data locally securely**. As soon as you are able to decrypt it an attacker can as well. That goes for EVERY encryption technique. No matter what you try.

You have to store the data or a different decryption key for each data point on a server and retrieve it one by one every time. You additionally have to make sure that the user does not just send 100s of requests and retrieves all data by hand.

Note that storing just one key on a server will result in the exact same thing as writing it hardcoded in the app. And not limiting the requests will just cause the attacker to need a little more time than just looking at an already decrypted local db.

Of course you can obfuscate it to make it seem like it has some good encryption behind it - but if someone **WANTS** to get the data, he will be able to.

Regarding the code in an ipa: you will not be able to see the original code but you will be able to see *some* code that produces the same output as the original code. As long as the device can produce the valid key, an attacker can as well.

I do not know if there is a huge community out there that is looking through random apps to steal some of its internal questions / answers / data, I doubt it.

You just have to make the product sooooo good that no competing product with the same data has any chance against it. The data itself can always be "stolen".

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't think it very likely that someone will try and steal the data but he went to a lot of effort to encrypt the data for the original windows version which he makes his living from and I've said that I will encrypt the iOS version so that's what I must do and if only 1 person manages to get the data and use it then I've let him down haven't I.

Comment: I am 10000000% sure that you can extract the data from the windows version as well - the problem is not iOS-specific. You cannot safely de- and encrypt data without an attacker to be able to the same thing.

Comment: I do appreciate that, I expect no one has tried to crack it, but if all the data was stored unencrypted then someone probably would have copied it by now. What this guy does with the windows version though is when a customer pays for and downloads the app from his website they then have to call him up and give him a code, he then gives them an unlock code. That has worked fine for him for over a decade but obviously not very user friendly/convenient and I can't see that system getting through the apple review process.

Comment: @KristianFox And I can guarantee you that everybody with some of this unlock codes can just extract the data if he tries to. It simply does not change anything, **locally stored data is not safe**.

Comment: But not all at once surely... If there are 10,000 encrypted questions stored (assume 256bit encryption) and only 50 are ever unencrypted and stored in memory at a time during an exam then can the other 9,950 questions be got at? I suppose you could just write another windows app that decrypts the data using that key, assuming the decryption process is standard.

Comment: @KristianFox I am not going to discuss security theory here, but assume the decryption takes 1 second per data point (which is actually far more than I expect), all data points can be extracted in under 3 hours. If you have the key, decryption is trivial.

Comment: @luk2302 All this is nice but... Without a HSM, TPM, Secure Element or equivalent there is not way to decrypt without making the key available in memory. That does not mean that there are not "Best Practices" that can be applied. What is missing is a clear statement of the level of security required, that is what is the data worth to the owner and attacker, who are the attackers, their capabilities and what are they willing/able to commit in resources. Security needs to be designed around the required criteria. It many be acceptable to have the key in memory during cryptographic operations.

Comment: My honest advice: listen carefully to @luk2302, you are in the phase where you are expert enough to recognize that plain data is bad but not expert enough to not consider "encryption" as a magic word. My much less honest advice: nobody will try to decrypt it, don't worry! If a great genius like cannot do it, who could? Go fine with the techno-encryption-bubbles! This way you feel confident and proud and I can advertise for the 5 min job of retrieving the "hidden" data as a "hacker only job" and get well paid for it by any competitor. We both win (extra money is good on holiday time!). :)